# Don't affect dropdown items of <select> when using CSS?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I'm styling an HTML `<select>` tag with CSS, but I want only the the clickable top part to be styled, not the items in the dropdown.

HTML:

```
<select id="entrytype" class="required">
    <option>Entity</option>
    <option>Object</option>
</select>
```

CSS:

```
.required {
    color: #D50000;
    background-color: #E4E4E4;
}
```

This works perfectly for the top part, as expected, but it also seems to be styling the items in the dropdown. How can I make this CSS **only** affect the top part?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style targeting the option elements, but it will not be a sure shot for every browser:

```
.required option {
    color: #000;
    background-color: #fff;
}
```

Dropdown selects are elements rendered by the OS in most older browsers and, therefore, can't be styled in a complete way.

I can confirm this works in IE11, Chrome 33 and Fifefox 20 (all Windows).

Comment: Is there any way to do this without overriding any other styles the options might have? For instance, if I have the body set to have a default text color of green, this will force the options to be black.